# sql data type error when dividing two figures

Tags: sql, error-handling, teradata, type-conversion

I have a simple query which states

```
convert(decimal(20,10),a.sumclk)/ nullif(convert(decimal(20,10),a.sumimp),0) as CTR1
```

When I run this I get a message saying 'Data Type "sumclk" does not match a Defined Type name.'

I looked around for what this means but I'm stuck

I'm using Teradata

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Teradata

Comment: Consider tagging your question with [Teradata] then, to help people with an answer or the same question find you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `convert(decimal(20,10),a.sumclk)` (which is MSSQL), try `CAST(a.sumclk as decimal(20,10))` (which I found on the Teradata forums: http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/explicit-casting)